# FFmpeg sidx atom not showing

Tags: ffmpeg, fragment, media-source, fmp4

I need to create a Fragment-MP4 with "sidx" box to create a streamable and seekable video to use it by MediaSource API
It is very easy to do it with Bento4 by using "--index" option, but I want to do it with ffmpeg because it has good other options like codec and bitrate and keyframes, It will be hard if I used both (ffmpeg, bento4) to create fmp4 by PHP exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `-movflags +dash` at a minimum. For a sidx per moof box, that's it. For a global sidx, in addition you have to set `global_sidx` as well, so `-movflags +dash+global_sidx`.

Comment: I really want to thank you I was using only global_sidx it was showing error when playing on chrome,

Comment: What should I use to specify timescale like 100000?

Comment: Track timescale? `-video_track_timescale 100000`